# Как посчитать количество чисел-палиндромов в большом промежутке?

Tags: python, палиндромы

Нужно посчитать количество палиндромов в промежутке от a до b.
Решается легко, если промежуток - до 10000
Но, как решить задачу, где нужно найти количество палиндромов в промежутке от 1.026.376 до 10**15 (квадриллиона)?
И желательно за быстрое время.
Перебором слишком долго, может есть какие-то формулы, где можно просто числа брать, не проверяя каждое на *палиндромность*?

Comment: Для суммы последовательных палиндромов можно вывести формулы без прямого суммирования всех палиндромов. Решение будет примерно за *k* или *k^2*, где *k* число цифр верхней границы.

Comment: сопоставьте заголовок вопроса с текстом, пожалуйста. сейчас из заголовка следует, что вам нужна сумма, а из текста вопроса - количество чисел.

Comment: @n1tr0xs, я разбился в лепёшку и решил для суммы. Гм. (Количество идёт в качестве бесплатного приложения).

Comment: @n1tr0xs, поменял название, простите!

Comment: Добавьте в вопрос код вашего решения. Не важно что оно медленное, важно чтобы оно было. Иначе вопрос закроют.

Answer (score 4):

*f(k)* - число чисел-палиндромов из *k* разрядов. Тогда

- *f(2k) = 9·10<sup>k-1</sup>*;
- *f(2k + 1) = 9·10<sup>k</sup>*.

Девятка отвечает за цифры старшего разряда - от единицы до девяти. Степень десятки - за остальные разряды из старшей половины числа.

*g(k)* - число чисел-палиндромов из не более чем *k* разрядов. Тогда

- *g(2k) = 2·10<sup>k</sup> - 2*;
- *g(2k + 1) = 11·10<sup>k</sup> - 2*.

Доказывается по индукции (*g(n + 1) = g(n) + f(n + 1)*).

*h(n)* - число чисел-палиндромов не более *n*. Я покажу на примере как его можно сосчитать быстро. Пусть *n = 345678*. Разобъём все палиндромы не более *n* на группы:

> ```
>      ? - палиндромы длины один. Их f(1)
>     ?? - палиндромы длины два. Их f(2)
>    ??? - палиндромы длины три. Их f(3)
>   ???? - палиндромы длины четыре. Их f(4)
>  ????? - палиндромы длины пять. Их f(5)
>
> 1????1 - таких палиндромов 100 (все палиндромные цифровые строки длины 4)
> 2????2 - тоже самое (первые цифры от единицы до 3 - 1)
>
> 30??03 - таких палиндромов 10 (все палиндромные цифровые строки длины 2)
> 31??13 - тоже самое
> 32??23 - тоже самое
> 33??33 - тоже самое (вторые цифры от нуля до 4 - 1)
>
> 340043 - такой палиндром один (все палиндромные цифровые строки длины 0)
> 341143 - тоже самое
> 342243 - тоже самое
> 343343 - тоже самое
> 344443 - тоже самое (третьи цифры от нуля до 5 - 1)
>
> 345543 - такой палиндром один, но надо отдельно проверить
>          что он не больше n
> ```

Получается такая программа:

```
def ps_count(k):
    """ число палиндромных строк длины k """
    return 10 ** ((k + 1) // 2)


def p_count_10p(k):
    """ число чисел-палиндромов не более k разрядов """
    return 10 ** ((k + 1) // 2) + 10 ** (k // 2) - 2


def p_count(n):
    """ число чисел-палиндромов не более n """

    if n == 0:
        return 0

    digits = tuple(map(int, str(n)))
    m = len(digits)

    # короткие палиндромы
    c = p_count_10p(m - 1)

    for i in range((m + 1) // 2):
        # палиндромы вида ABC????CBA
        c += (digits[i] - (0 if i > 0 else 1)) * ps_count(m - 2 * (i + 1))

    if digits[:m // 2 - 1::-1] <= digits[(m + 1) // 2:]:
        # палиндром вида ABCDEEDCBA
        c += 1

    return c


def main():
    n1, n2 = map(int, input().split())
    # число чисел-палиндромов диапазоне [n1, n2]
    print(p_count(n2) - p_count(n1 - 1))


main()
```

> ```
> echo 1026376 1_000_000_000_000_000  | python pcount.py
> 109997973
> ```

Программа работает за логарифмическое время. Её можно переделать для расчёта суммы палиндромов. Первоначально так и было, но вопрос изменился и ответ упростился.

Answer (score 1):

Я предлагаю  от 1.026.376 до следующего разряда 10 000 000 проверить перебором, а далее поразрядно 10^7 .. 10^8 ..10^n
по формуле: если n четное, то количество палиндромов 10^(n//2)-10^(n//2-1),
если n  не четное, то количество палиндромов 10^((n+1)//2)-10^((n+1)//2-1)

```
например:
10^2 количество палиндромов 9
10^3 количество палиндромов 90
10^4 количество палиндромов 90
10^5 количество палиндромов 900
10^6 количество палиндромов 900
 

s=0
for i in range(1026376,10**7):
    sss=str(i)
    if sss==sss[::-1]:
        s+=1
print('->',s)
for n in range(8,15+1): # Ошибочно начинал с 10^7
    if n%2==0:
        s+=10**(n//2)-10**(n//2-1)
    else:
        s+=10**((n+1)//2)-10**((n+1)//2-1)

print(s)

-> 8973
109997973
```

Comment: Проверьте свои формулы, например, для диапазонов 100-1000 и 1000-10000

Comment: @MBo вы правы, формула была не верна, исправил на другую, прогнал до 10^7

Comment: Можно еще проще `9*10**((n-1)//2)` в обоих случаях, т.е. if не нужен. И для данной конкретной границы можно пройти короткий диапазон 1000000..1026376, **вычитая** единицы, а потом пройти диапазоны, включая 10^6..10^7. Результат, кстати, у меня 109997973

Comment: Это еще одна ошибка, до 10^7 уже сосчитал, и нужно начинать с 10^8

Comment: Перебор это не спортивно. Есть решение без перебора.

Comment: @Stanislav Volodarskiy Ну мы видим, что до 1 026 376 уже проехало 10 палиндромов с нулями (1 000 001..1 009 001)+ 10 палиндромов с (1010101 .. 1019101) и еще 7 с двоечкой (1020201..1026201) и как посоветовал @MBo, добавить количество палиндромов по разрядам получаем: `print((9000-(10+10+7))+sum([9*10**((n-1)//2) for n in range(8,15+1)]))`

Comment: Эту схему имеет смысл реализовать в виде программы.