# Найдите количество целых чисел-палиндромов в заданном промежутке (включая границы). JAVA

Tags: java, алгоритм, палиндромы

На вход программы подаются 2 числа в строчке: границы интервала поиска `a` и `b` (известно, что `a < b`).

Найдите количество целых чисел-палиндромов в заданном промежутке (включая границы).

Представлять число в виде строки нельзя, задачу необходимо решить с использованием стандартных арифметических операций.

Требуется решить с помощью джавы.

Comment: Здесь не решают задачи. Если ноль, то возьми учебник.

Comment: Чем ещё пользоваться нельзя, кроме строк?

Answer (score 2):

Данную задачу можно решать разными способами, которые будут значительно отличаться по эффективности.

Самое простое, понятное / логичное, но не самое быстрое решение  заключается в переборе всех чисел из заданного диапазона с проверкой, является ли такое число палиндромом.

Готовый код не приводится в педагогических целях, будет только описание алгоритма и базовых вещей.

1. Понадобится определить метод (функцию), который/ая будет проверять, является ли входное целое число (неотрицательное) палиндромом или нет (условная сигнатура: `static boolean isPalindrome(int n)`)
2. Числа "длиной" 1, т.е. меньшие 10, по определению являются палиндромами.  Соответственно, числа от 10 и выше, которые оканчиваются на 0, палиндромами являться не будут.
3. Потребуется создать и завести массив `int[] d` для сохранения цифр входного числа `n`.
   Размер такого массива должен быть достаточным, чтобы запомнить все цифры наибольшего 32-битного целого числа `Integer.MAX_VALUE` = 2<sup>31</sup> - 1 = 2'147'483'647, то есть, 10 знаков.
   Также стоит завести счётчик для длины числа (`int len = 0;`).
4. В первом цикле заполняем массив цифр при помощи операции `%` (нахождения остатка от деления по модулю 10) и инкрементируем счётчик длины, при этом исходное число последовательно сдвигается вправо на один десятичный разряд (уменьшается) путём деления на 10, пока не останется 0.
5. Получив массив цифр и вычислив длину исходного числа, во втором цикле проверяем собственно, является ли число палиндромом любым удобным способом, сравнивая цифры в начале и конце числа (индексы `i` и `len - 1 - i`).
   Как только обнаружено расхождение в цифрах, возвращается значение `false` (не палиндром).
   Если цикл завершён до конца (проверены все цифры), возвращаем `true` (найден палиндром).

Затем реализуем второй метод, принимающий на вход два числа `a` и `b`, `a < b`, со счётчиком палиндромов, и вызывающий в цикле от `a` до `b` (включительно) предыдущий метод `isPalindrome()`.
Условная сигнатура `static int countPalindromes(int a, int b)`.

В основном методе `main` обеспечиваем ввод чисел `a` и `b` (например при помощи класса `java.util.Scanner`, у которого есть метод для чтения целых чисел из потока ввода `nextInt`), вызываем `countPalindromes` и выводим результаты его работы (`System.out.println / System.out.printf`).

---

Пример гораздо более эффективного решения на Питоне без перебора и проверки на палиндромность можно найти в [ответе](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1521089/386633) от Станислава Володарского на похожий вопрос [Как посчитать количество чисел-палиндромов в большом промежутке?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1520866/).

Comment: Нет необходимости строить проверять все числа на палиндромность чтобы сосчитать их количество в диапазоне. Думаю, число палиндромов вычисляется анализом цифр чисел *a* и *b* без перебора чисел в диапазоне или построения палиндромов.

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy, разумеется, я привёл ссылку на ваше решение на питоне.